# best way to write jQuery's replaceWith() in natural JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, replacewith

Having trouble with a function hitting the page as soon as possible, so i need to write it in pure javascript and include it in the head. not sure how to go about it, because as i understand it, by using .replace() the new element will be moved to a different location on the page. jQuery's replaceWith() behavior is ideal.

```
$("#imagefiles").replaceWith("<input type='file' name='imagefiles' id='imagefiles' />");
```

Comment: What is the problem with using jQuery again?

Comment: `.replace()` is for strings. Please don't use it for DOM. Could you describe your issue a little better? Are you saying you want an element to be replaced as soon as it appears, and not wait for the rest of the DOM to be ready?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var image = document.getElementById('imagefiles'), parent = image.parentNode,
tempDiv = document.createElement('div');

tempDiv.innerHTML = "<input type='file' name='imagefiles' id='imagefiles' />"

var input = tempDiv.childNodes[0];

parent.replaceChild(input, image);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fnvjR/)

---

EDIT as per am not i am:

```
var image = document.getElementById('imagefiles'), parent = image.parentNode,
input = document.createElement('input');
input.id = input.name = "imagefiles";
input.type = 'file';

parent.replaceChild(input, image);
```

### [edited DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EjTtG/)

Comment: Why the `div`? It'll be faster and less code to just create the `input` directly. `input = document.createElement('input'); input.type = "file"; input.id = input.name = "imagefiles";`

Comment: @qwertymk it works in jsFiddle, but my webinspector is showing an error on the final line: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Comment: @technopeasant: dude, you gotta vote more to get people to answer you, 11 votes all time when you asked 128 questions?

Comment: @technopeasant: You can pick up some invisible and illegal characters if you copy/paste from jsFiddle. Better to copy the code from here instead.

Answer (score 3):

```js
  const node = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html').body.childNodes[0];
  document.getElementById(id).replaceWith(node);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let element = document.getElementById("imagefiles");
element.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend","<input type='file' name='imagefiles' id='imagefiles' />");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Years later. There is now an childNode.replaceWith() but it is not strictly equivalent to the JQuery replaceWith(); Nor is it compatible with I.E.

The above code creates a document fragment from the given HTML, and inserts it after the original element in the DOM and then deletes the original element, effectively replacing it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith