# How to replace all img tags in HTML string with <a><img></a>?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift, uiwebview

I have HTML string and I open it in UIWebView. Now, I want to make all my images clickable, to put them into link tags like:

Was:

```
<img src="..." />
```

Became:

```
<a href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
```

Is there any easy solution?

I've tried to find all  tags and replace them inside of the string, but it was very painful.

I've tried that:

```
let js = "var a=document.createElement('a');a.href='http://mylink.com';var image = document.getElementById('mydiv').getElementsByTagName('img')[0];b=a.appendChild(image);document.getElementById('mydiv').appendChild(a);"

self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(js)
```

but it did not help me

Comment: how about injecting a javascript link into the page, and using javascript code to manipulate the dom? if using jquery in that script, you can use the $.wrap function

Comment: @CodeToad look at my question please. I've added my JS code

Comment: is there jquery on the page?

Comment: @CodeToad no. I want to do it with simple JS

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165262/best-way-to-write-jquerys-replacewith-in-natural-javascript

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: No, there is not an easy solution. Don't do that. Trying to parse and change HTML source from a client app is a horrible idea, and will always be very painful. It's kind of like trying to perform brain surgery on yourself with a sawzall, a mirror, and some old dental tools.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I want to make my images inside of UIWebView clickable and on click I open gallery with these images. What do you advice me?

Comment: I advise you not to do what you are planning. Failing that, have lots of headache medicine on hand, and be prepared for a very fragile app that you have to tweak constantly to adapt to the almost infinite variations of HTML code you get from different sites.