# how to update table's row each time data change?

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to make table using JavaScript.
I have created a function makeTable to generate table data each time it is been called.
My Code -

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th>User Name</th>
                    <th>Audio</th>
                    <th>Video</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody id="myTable">
                </tbody>
            </table>


    function onMemberListUpdate(members) {
        console.log("member updated")
        buildTable(members);
    }

function buildTable(data){
        console.log("build table function called", data);
        var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
        for(var i =0; i<data.length; i++){
            var row = `<tr> <td>${data[i].name}</td> <td>${data[i].audio_muted}</td> <td>${data[i].video_muted}</td> <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Audio</button></td>`
            table.innerHTML += row;

        }

    }
```

Issue that I am facing here is whenever member list updates and `onMemberListUpdate` function gets called it calls `buildTable` function that makes new row each time I don't want to create new row each time instead I want to update the existing table data. How can I achieve this thing please help

Answer (score 1):

Consider marking each row with an attribute that you can use to find it later when you need to update it.

You can (for example) add `class="item-id-${data[i].id}"` to the `tr` (as below)

```js
function buildTable(data){
        console.log("build table function called", data);
        var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
        for(var i =0; i<data.length; i++){
            var row = `<tr class="item-id-${data[i].id}"> <td>${data[i].name}</td> <td>${data[i].audio_muted}</td> <td>${data[i].video_muted}</td> <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Audio</button></td>`
            table.innerHTML += row;

        }

    }
```

then you can call `updateRow` and in that function you can get the row by doing `$(".item-id-123")` and you can create new html that replaces it, so something like this:

```js
function updateRow(data) {
  $(`.item-id-${data.id}`).replaceWith(`
    <tr class="item-id-${data.id}">
      <td>${data.name}</td>
      <td>${data.audio_muted}</td>
      <td>${data.video_muted}</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Audio</button></td>
    </tr>`);
}
```

Comment: thank you but I am getting "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'replaceWith')" err I need to call updateRow function inside onMemberListUpdate right ?

Comment: sorry the example uses jquery you can do the same without jquery as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165262/best-way-to-write-jquerys-replacewith-in-natural-javascript